# How to save keyboard shortcuts in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

After 1 or 2 years if I need to format of my Windows PC with a fresh installation, how can I keep my keyboard shortcuts that I configured manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`

Click one of the little "download" icons...

[image]

Left = Save As
Right = Save a Copy

This will place a file where you want it. Saving to the desktop is the easiest place.

Now merely drag that `.kys` file onto the Photoshop application icon. Photoshop will ask you if you want to save the current key configuration... and then apply the `.kys` settings.

Alternatively, you may be able to navigate to `hdd/users/[you]/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop (version)/Presets/Keyboard Shortcuts` and copy the `.kys` files there and then place them in the same location after a reinstall.

In fact, I will generally just copy the entire `Presets` folder and then replace it after a reinstall. Or copy it from a previous backup.

<sub>(Sorry I only know the Macintosh path.)</sub>

Comment: The “Save As”, then dragging the .kys file onto the Photoshop application icon routine worked like a charm.
Thank you!